# Alea GPU Free Memory

Tags: c#, gpu, aleagpu

Anyone know  how to determine `free/available` global memory on a GPU, similar to the `CUDA "cudaMemGetInfo(&free_byte, &total_byte);?`.

I've searched the `Alea` website for the API trying to locate a property to determine free bytes, but nothing seems to fit the bill.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a high level API for that.
But you can use low level CUDA interop this way :

```
private unsafe void ShowMem()
{
    IntPtr free;
    IntPtr total;
    Alea.CUDAInterop.cuSafeCall(Alea.CUDAInterop.cuMemGetInfo(&free, &total));
    Console.Out.WriteLine($"free={free} - total={total}");
}
```